# how to install XMHF on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am new to linux OS. According to the requirement of my project I have to install extensible Hypervisor Framework( XMHF) and then build the required hypapp over it. Grub is supposed to load the XMHF at boot time and then the ubuntu OS has to laod over it, But when i am trying to boot the system according to the steps mentioned to install XMHF the system stops at the Starting up.... state at the time of booting. I dont know where i have done mistake. I have checked it many times but nothing useful. Can anyone please help me with this?? "Installing XMHF"  manual can be found at http://xmhf.sourceforge.net/doc/xmhf/doc/installing-xmhf.md.html

My grub entry for XMHF is

title XMHF

rootnoverify (hd0,0)                 // as i have no primary partition for the hard drive

kernel /boot/init-x86.bin

module /boot/hypervisor.bin.gz

modulenounzip (hd0)+1

Comment: what is the error that it is showing

Comment: it is not showing any error just after giving the modulenounzip command it shows Starting Up...... and it gets stuck there, until i reboot the system using power button

Comment: I am in immense need of the solution to this problem.Someone Kindly help!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

I had to properly configure serial output, either physically or serial-over-lan, to see XMHF's output. In my case, I missed a Intel VT related switch in BIOS.

How to configure serial console can be found here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-serial-console-howto/

Comment: Hi, could you add a brief summary of the answer as well as including a link? We do this in case the link ever changes/ goes down the information is still here.

Comment: Thanks ShawnS, its awesome to know someone tried the same which I couldn't accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

go through this http://xmhf.sourceforge.net/doc/xmhf/doc/installing-xmhf.md.html   this will be helpful :D